# classic asp page posting to mvc3 controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp-classic

I am currently working with integrating a classic asp site with MVC3. I have some questions on some areas of the integration that I would like some feedback on.

Firstly, I have a asp page posting to an MVC controller action. I have very little scope to modify the asp page. I want to take the form fields posted from the asp page and map them in to a model object. The posted values have obscure names such as "my_name" which I want to map to Name property on the model object. Is the best way of doing this via a Model Binder or is there an alternative?

Next question I have is a follow on from the previous, I am concerned with any cross site scripting so want to check the values of the posted variables to be valid and contain no strange characters etc. Is there something built in to MVC3 that does this out of the box?

When the asp page posts to the controller action, I would like to show a waiting icon while the controller action is processing as the controller action could take 10 seconds plus as it must call external systems etc. Therefore I don't want the post to seem as its hanging. Is it possible to wire up the controller action to return a view with a waiting icon, while the main body of the action is processing in the background and once complete redirects to another page?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the best way of doing this via a Model Binder or is there an
>   alternative?

The best way of doing is a model binder. You can have a custom model binder to take care of the ASP scenario that maps the `my_name` to `Name`. Mostly you should have a separate action to handle the requests coming from classic asp and you can link the custom model binder to only this action.

> Is there something built in to MVC3 that does this out of the box?

The request validation is enabled as default in MVC. So if an user tries to post a script block to the action MVC will throw exception. Of course you can switch off request validation by decorating the action with `ValidateInput(false)` if you need.

For long running actions you have to use [asynccontrollers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx).